# Classpath trouble with Bruce Eckel's TIJ3

Tags: java, classpath

I'm having some trouble running an example from Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java 3. Specifically, when I type

```
ant build
```

from the code root directory, as instructed on the website, I am able to compile all examples up to chapter 14 (directory c14), which is normal because I haven't installed a couple of libraries required to build the targets of chapter 14. However, when I cd to the directory corresponding to chapter 3 (c03) and invoke javac on the Assignment.java file, I get the following:

```
jason@debian-laptop:~/code/tij3/code/c03$ javac Assignment.java 
Assignment.java:5: package com.bruceeckel.simpletest does not exist
...
```

where "..." refers to other compile-time errors which I get because of the compiler's inability to find the package com.bruceeckel.simpletest package.

My classpath, as you will note, includes the home code directory of TIJ3:

```
jason@debian-laptop:~/code/tij3/code/c03$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:..:/home/jason/code/tij3/code/
```

So I'm guessing that the directory tree nested in that directory should be well seen by the java compiler. After all, ant runs well. For the record, my Java version is 1.6.0_26:

```
jason@debian-laptop:~/code/tij3/code/c03$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any help with this would be immensely appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: The problem is that the compiler is unable to find the imports from `com.bruceeckel.simpletest`. Did you build them (using `build.xml` in the `com` folder) before compiling your Assignment class?

Comment: I have, unfortunately. I wish it were that easy.

Comment: Hm, after following some advice I found here: [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.gr/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) and actually using the -classpath option to plug in the CLASSPATH environmental variable which I showed earlier, my problem was solved, which makes me think that the CLASSPATH I have in my .bashrc file is being overriden. Any clue as to how I can hunt for the application that's overriding the CLASSPATH? Marking this solved, btw.